# JQuery Tabs in C# MVC to stay on reload

Tags: c#, mvc

I am working on a C# MVC website. in which i am using tabs.I was trying to stay on the current tab when page refreshes.

I achieved this by following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1) {
        var newURL = location.href;
        window.history.pushState('object', document.title, newURL);
    }
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if (activeTab) {
        $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```

This is working fine. But if the page is load by `RedirectToAction` from another page then it showing last opened tab, I needed to show the first tab.

So I added a hidden input field in the html.

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.IsRefresh" id="IsRefresh" />
```

On `$(document).ready` i change url as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1) {
        var newURL = location.href.replace("?str=true", "");
        window.history.pushState('object', document.title, newURL);
    }
});
```

and in GET checks for this `bool str` and set IsRefresh as false

```
#region Check Is Page Refresh
if (str != null)
{
    if ((bool)str)
    {
        item.IsRefresh = false;
    }
    else
    {
        item.IsRefresh = true;
    }
}
else
{
    item.IsRefresh = true;
}
str = false;
#endregion
```

so if `IsRefresh` is false then it is page refresh and else it is `RedirectToAction`.

So i changed the code as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');

    <!-- added these lines -->
    var refresgh = $("#IsRefresh").val();
    if (!refresgh) {
        activeTab = "";
    }

    if (activeTab) {
        $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```

Now its working fine, but sometimes i get the feeling that on page refresh different tab is showing. Is something wrong with my code?

Is there any better solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If browser compatibility matrix satisfies your requirements (see [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=navigation)) then there is a simpler way to check if page is reloaded, read `window.performance.navigation.type` value. For reload event value is `TYPE_RELOAD` then you may simply drop your `hidden` input and:

```
if (window.performance.navigation.type != 1) {
    activeTab = "";
}
```

See also [W3C specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#sec-navigation-info-interface) for further details.

---

If you're not targeting IE you may want to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of string concatenation, for example:

```
$(`#myTab a[href="${activeTab}"]`).tab('show');
```

---

Value you're persisting in `localStorage` does not need to be retained across different sessions then you'd better use `sessionStorage` instead. It also has the advantage to be isolated by window (or tab).

---

You may want to use `let` and, where appropriate, `const` instead of `var`.

---

To put everything all together you may want to revert the condition you're checking to simplify your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });

    if (window.performance.navigation.type === 1) {
        const activeTab = sessionStorage.getItem('activeTab');
        $(`#myTab a[href="${activeTab}"]`).tab('show');
    }
});
```

---

The [recommended](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) way to attach an handler to the `ready` event is:

```
$(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Absolutely nothing wrong with the *verbose* way (which BTW I find more clear).

---

I add this only because you may find it useful in future, to detect a page refresh may be done also server side, see [asp.net mvc - Detecting page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8244437/1207195).

Comment: `window.performance.navigation.type` is new to me, and it reduce my code and looks great. thanks